# adding a file at publish time

Tags: c#, winforms, publish

I completed my winform application.

I want to add a csv file. So my application will reach with this path.

How can I get published locastion's path?

Comment: Do you want to do this as an embedded resource or do you want to want to include this as content with your executable?

Comment: I tried to content. But I dont know the embedded resource means?

Comment: An embedded resource exists inside the assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean following with published locations:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
Environment.GetFolderPath(...)
```

with one of following parameter

```
SpecialFolder.ApplicationData
SpecialFolder.Desktop
...
```

etc.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx

Comment: +1 but watch out for currentdirectory, file dialogs [can change it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2049126/119477)

Answer (score 0):

If you programmatically want to get your form's execution path to access your CSV, use

`string path = (new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath;`
inside your form.

and then `Path.Combine(path, CSVFilename);`