# Is there any event to notify when Environment.CurrentDirectory got changed?

Tags: c#, .net

In my code I am trying to read a file using `File.Open()` with relative path. But some times the current directory is getting changed and directory not found exception is coming.

I am trying to figure out where is `Environment.CurrentDirectory` is getting changed. I checked the [Directory.SetCurrentDirectory](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,1172) method but its calling to native method.

Is there any event which will notify me when `Environment.CurrentDirectory` has changed? How do I find out where exactly is directory changed?

I have tried putting break point in all occurrence of `Environment.CurrentDirectory` and `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory()`.

Comment: Need a bit more context. Presumably it's your code, so any directory changes are intentional. I'd keep looking for calls to change it.

Comment: @dan some people may not consider using file open dialog as intentional call to change current folder.

Comment: No.  By far the best thing to do is *never* use it.  You never need it.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could check if the current directory is correct before the File.Open() call, or, store the correct directory you want to use and use an absolute path for File.Open()

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary more details, I've never seen this attribute changing during runtime.

1. If you are running the executable from Start Menu ou another shortcuts, the current directory will change, check the property "Starts In".

   2. If you are deploying a Click Once application, every version was installed at different folder, and you won't find files saved at same executable folder.
   3. I found some references that OpenFileDialogs (and opendirectorydialog) changes the Environment.CurrentDirectory.

Source: [OpenFileDialog and Environment.CurrentDirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049126/openfiledialog-and-environment-currentdirectory)

Comment: Feels like this post answers some other interpretation of "current directory changes".