# Form.OpenFileDialog make BinaryFormatter.Serialize stop working

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem that I don't know how to solve.
I have have a Form that open a OpenFileDialog to add data.
But after I call OpenFileDialog.Show() I can't save anything with BinaryFormatter.Serialize.
The strange thing is that I doesn't even need to use the data that I have from the OpenFileDialog, only to open the dialog make the subsequent call to Serialize to stop working.

Stop working means that no new data is saved.

I don't get any error messages or exceptions, it just silently fail.
Do anyone have any pointers to when the problem could be.
I used the XmlSerializer when I added the OpenFileDialog and switched to BinaryFormatter.Serialize in hope that it should be more resistant to whatever problem I have so I'm pretty sure it affects XmlSerializer to.

I'm using .NET 4.0

Relevant code (I hope) is:
Save:

```
    public void Save()
    {
        File.Delete(fileName);
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
            bin.Serialize(stream, contactList);
        }

    }
```

Load:

```
  private void LoadContactList()
    {
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            using (Stream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                contactList = (List<Contact>)bin.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // start on a new database
        }
   }
```

use of OpenFileDialog:

```
   private void btnPhoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DialogResult.OK == ofdPhoto.ShowDialog(this.Parent))
        {
            // signalling that the dialog have been used have have
            // useful data
            ofdPhoto.Tag = (object)true;
        }
    }
```

What I am saving is List:

```
List<Contact> contactList;
```

I have only Person in the list

```
[Serializable]
public class Person : Contact
{
    #region variables and properties

    //public string Photo { get; set; }
    public string Photo;

    private string lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { lastName = value; base.ComparisonKey = value; }
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    //  no contructor
}
```

**Edit**

In the end of the program I save all data:

```
  private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        data.Save();
    }
```

The file name path that I get with the `OpenFileDialog` is for a photo.
The path is stripped and only the file name is stored. That part I have checked.
 The file name is stored in a Person object, the Person object is stored in List
and in the end of program the whole array is persisted.
**End edit**
It doesn't depend on the format on the string I am loading

Edit: I have called Dispose on the OpenFileDialog before I save with the BinaryFormatter.Serializer
When I comment out the contents of btnPhoto_Click it BinaryFormatter.Serializer works.

I would appriciate any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't saved my file with an absolute path but with just a file name. When OpenFileDialog was used the current directory was changed and the data, the array was stored in current directory that was a totally different place than in the beginning of the program.

And when I restarted the program, the current directory was reset and all the data seemed to be thrown away.
One solution is described in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930816/why-does-openfiledialog-change-my-working-directory)
Or just save current directory in a field [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938421/getting-the-applications-directory-from-a-wpf-application)