# pictureBox.Image.Save() in c# doesn't work

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

I don't understand this issue. Because this usually worked till now. 
This method is reaction on click for saving image on pictureBox which is called canvas.
I load the Image on canvas and then do some edits. Then I want save the image.
If I click on the printScreenButton before loading image it works, but when I load the image it stops working.
Where could be the problem?

```
private void printScreenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          canvas.Image.Save("name.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png); 
      }
```

**Edit:** 
Work == file called name.png is created 
Doesn't work == file called name.png isn't created

Code for drawing an image == putting on picture box

```
` private void drawTransformedBitmap(Matrix transformationMatrix) 
        {
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(canvasBitmapShow); //prepare graphics

            if (antialiasing)
            {
                g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
            }
            else 
            {
                g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
            }

            g.Clear(Color.White); //clear canvas

            g.Transform.Reset(); //clear transformations
            g.Transform = transformationMatrix; //set transformations from transformationMatrix
            g.DrawImage(canvasBitmapTarget, 0, 0); //draw from Bitmap called canvasBitmapTarget

            canvas.Invalidate(); //refresh canvas
        }`
```

Initialization at the begining:

```
canvasBitmapShow = new Bitmap(canvas.Width, canvas.Height);
canvasBitmapSource = new Bitmap(canvas.Width, canvas.Height);
canvasBitmapTarget = new Bitmap(canvas.Width, canvas.Height);
canvasBitmapBackup = new Bitmap(canvas.Width, canvas.Height);

canvas.Image = canvasBitmapShow; //set the Image
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What is the actual problem? "It doesnt work" doesn't tell us much.

Comment: please provide some more code like the one you're putting an image into the picture-box.

Comment: Put a `try..catch(Exception ex)` block around the `Save` call and take a look at the resulting exception.

Comment: are you sure that file is not created ? Maybe is just in the wrong folder, set a full path for filename

Comment: @AntonioBakula yes I'm sure its the path where is the .exe file and when I try to save it before loading picture => the file is created, so I also try to delete it, and I try it again after loading the image on canvas => no file created, I also tryed to refresh the folder => stil no file.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'll try it, but shouldn't it give me some error when there is an eror without puttiong try ... catch? I see no error, but i'll try try... catch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> canvas.Image.Save("name.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

*Never* write code like this, you don't specify the full path of the file.  Which makes the actual location of the file heavily dependent on the current working directory of your program.  The value of Environment.CurrentDirectory.   Which can change unexpectedly, using an OpenFileDialog without the RestoreDirectory property set to true would be an example.

If you get no exception then you can be sure that the file got saved.  Exactly *where* it got saved is a guess.  At least use either SaveFileDialog or Environment.GetFolderPath() to get a predictable directory name.  Also, the default working directory won't work on your user's machine, you cannot write to c:\program files.

Comment: OMFG, I would jump from the my boots after mistakes like that. Thanks a lot. I really haven't any clue that open file dialog do that. The pictures are of course saved in folder from the original picture was loaded. I'll use SaveFileDialog like you advised. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

When you load an image, I suppose using an [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx), you changed the [CurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx), simply set [RestoreDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.restoredirectory.aspx) to true to prevent this behavior, but beware, apparently it sometimes behave differently across OS according to answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930816/why-does-openfiledialog-change-my-working-directory)

Maybe the easiest way to get around the problem is by using the [SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) to save your file.