# Path.GetRandomFileName vs Path.GetTempFileName

Tags: c#

Base on recommendation from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename(v=vs.110).aspx 
I have replaced  GetTempFileName with GetRandomFileName to get a name for the temp file. And it cause a problem. Sometimes GetRandomFileName return not a file name but location in System32 folder. And of cause users with no admin rights are having an error that file is not found.
Do I missed anything?

Here is a code:

`string tempFileName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
FileStream tempFileStream = null;
tempFileStream = File.Open(tempFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)`;

later on when I try to access that file by code:

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(tempFileName);
```

I have an error:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\25ddubwt.qsc' is denied.

I realised that when user initiate a program by using menu from Windows/Start button current directory for the application will be System32

Comment: Any example of a location being returned instead of a filename?

Comment: Here is a C# Fiddle demonstrating what Alex K is saying. Notice it only prints a random filename: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dqKbUy Also, GetRandomFileName() doesn't create a file while GetTempFileName creates a zero byte file and returns the full path to it.

Comment: I have to edit my question. If you initiate your exe by using sortcut on Windows Start button menu current directory became System32.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`GetTempFileName()` returns a full path, `GetRandomFileName()` does not.

If you assume `GetRandomFileName()` has a path and write to it the file may well end up in System32 if thats the current directory.

To fix create a full path:

```
string fname = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName());
```

Comment: It would be a reasonable explanation. But it is not a current directory. and it is happening only 10-25% of the time.

Comment: One will point to c:\something\temp\ the other will not, thats the only difference and its quite a big one.  Something else may be changing the directory - which is why you should always specify an absolute path where possible.

Comment: Does it mean that sometimes current directory can be System32 and sometimes not? Depends on what?

Comment: It's best to not assume the location of current directory, being there are any number of reasons why the current directory might change for example OpenFileDialog as discussed in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930816/why-does-openfiledialog-change-my-working-directory)

Comment: It may be a good idea to explicitly mention that `GetRandomFileName()` does not create the file on disk while `GetTempFileName()` does it.